Celery tasks are stucked in a state RUNNING
Let's say I have a worker with specific queue. When this worker in a process of task execution and worker crashes (for example I manually kill docker container), code in my application that monitoring the task by AsyncResult.ready() returns STARTED and flower shows STARTED as well. Why isn't task FAILED?
